# How can I remove the part below the carousel?

Tags: reactjs, image, carousel, responsive

I am using react-responsive-carousel to add carousel in react.
Here is my code:

```
<Carousel autoPlay interval="5000" transitionTime="5000">
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/400?img=1" />
                        <p className="legend">My Classic Still 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/400?img=2" />
                        <p className="legend">My Classic Still 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/400?img=3" />
                        <p className="legend">My Classic Still 3</p>
                    </div>
                </Carousel>
```

how can I remove the part below it. I marked the part in the picture which I want to remove.
[image]

Comment: can you share your code in sandbox ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the  showThumbs props to false like below

```
<Carousel autoPlay interval="5000" transitionTime="5000" showThumbs={false}>
```

Comment: is there any way to hide thumbnails only when mobile browser?

Comment: Silly me, I was trying to pass in false as a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pass `showThumbs={false}` to **`Corousel`** component

```
             <Carousel autoPlay interval="5000" 
                 transitionTime="5000" showThumbs={false}>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/400?img=1" />
                        <p className="legend">My Classic Still 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/400?img=2" />
                        <p className="legend">My Classic Still 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/400?img=3" />
                        <p className="legend">My Classic Still 3</p>
                    </div>
                </Carousel>
```